# Why doesn't this spawn a root shell?

Tags: macos, bash, root

I'm on OSX 10.8.

Before my experiment it's like this:

```
Nathan-der-Graue:~ max$ ls -l /bin/bash
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1333920 17 Feb 15:22 /bin/bash
```

Then I run

```
Nathan-der-Graue:~ max$ sudo chmod +s /bin/bash
```

I expected this to make bash always come up as a root shell, but it seems that it didn't change anything to bash's behaviour:

```
Nathan-der-Graue:~ max$ /bin/bash
bash-3.2$ whoami
max
```

I know this isn't a good idea at all. Where is my mistake? I guess I have misunderstood the +s-flag.

Comment: Making /bin/bash setuid is likely to break parts of OS X itself, because it's used for a variety of scripts within the OS, some of which *should not* run as root. If you want a setuid shell, give it a different name to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because bash explicitly checks for the "running setuid" case, and sets its EUID to be the same as the RUID – in other words, it drops all privileges it might have gained from the setuid bit.

---

Processes have several separate UIDs – the two primary ones are the **RUID** (real UID, often just "UID"), which determines who owns the process, and the **EUID** (effective UID), which determines the privileges that process has.

When the EUID is 0 (root), the process can set any RUID or EUID it wants; and if the process doesn't have root privileges, it can still set its RUID to be the same as the EUID or vice versa.

When the *setuid* bit is set, it affects *only* the new process' EUID, not RUID – in other words, it only gives the file owner's privileges, not the identity. Try it again with `/usr/bin/id`.

Comment: So, I didn't get it wrong, it's just that bash behaves in a special way to prevent this? Is there any other way to achieve my wanted scenario?

Comment: @MaxRied: Write a small C program that sets the RUID to the EUID before starting bash. `#include <unistd.h> /*newline*/ int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { setgid(getegid()); setuid(geteuid()); argv[0] = "bash"; execvp(argv[0], argv); }`

Answer (score -1):

If you have `sudo` privileges, you can run

```
sudo -s
```

to get a root shell.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: I suspect it is because you did not answer the question. The question is "**Why** did setuid_bash not work. Did I misunderstand the s-bit." It is not "how do I get a root shell".

Comment: True, I made the (unwarranted?) assumption that this was an XY problem, and he just wanted to have a root shell.